# How can I get the extract the previous year (2020) using Sys.Date()?

Tags: r

`Sys.Date()` Gives me today's month, year, and date (`2021-08-09`), but how can I use `Sys.Date()` to get to extract the previous year (2020)?
Thank you!

Comment: `as.integer(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y)) - 1` or `lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - 1`.

Comment: `as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$year + 1900 - 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `Date` or `Datetime` object can be converted to a `POSIXlt` which (see the help) has a number of subcomponents.  Which includes the year -- but expressed relative to have base of 1900.  So as this

```
> as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$year + 1900
[1] 2021
>
```

give you the current year (adding the 'base' of 1900), this

```
> as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$year + 1900 - 1
[1] 2020
>
```

gives you the preceding year.

Comment: Fine, I didn't know about the subcomponents. +1

Comment: (When one has used other programming languages, it sort-of becomes more natural to expect these features. It is something the C library has, and hence many other languages implement. And it is generally faster and more reliable than going via string formatting and re-parsing or subsetting.)

Answer (score 3):

With `base R` use `format` to extract the year and convert it into an integer

```r
as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - 1
```

Or use `lubridate`'s `year`-function

```r
library(lubridate)

year(Sys.Date()) - 1
# or to save three letters
year(today()) - 1
```

Based on Dirk Eddelbuettel's comment here a benchmark of the given answers:

```r
library(lubridate)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  base   = as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$year + 1900 - 1,
  string = as.numeric(substr(Sys.Date(), 1, 4))-1,
  lubri  = year(Sys.Date()) - 1,
  lubri2 = year(today()) - 1,
  format = as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")) - 1,
  times  = 10000)

#> Unit: microseconds
#> expr    min     lq      mean        median    uq      max       neval
#> base    20.9    22.3    24.91809    22.9      23.8    4258.5    10000
#> string  50.4    53.3    58.38770    54.8      57.4    7742.0    10000
#> lubri   24.9    26.3    27.90740    27.0      28.0     126.2    10000
#> lubri2  53.2    56.1    61.60990    57.5      60.1    4514.6    10000
#> format  36.6    38.4    41.82726    39.2      40.6    4546.1    10000
```